# Specify from and to time as well as dates for promotions (Magento 2 CE)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, promotions, third-party-module

I am wanting to add a Cart Price Rule within my Magento shop (Community Edition 2.1.4) that must be active within a certain date and time range.

Within the Admin, if you head to **Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules** and either add or edit a rule, you can very easily pick a date when the rule is to be made active (From), and a date for when you want it to be made inactive (To). However there doesn't seem to be an option to select the time as well, especially if it's to happen on one day only (e.g. between 9am - 5pm).

I don't mind paying for an extension, however Google has come up with nothing that fits the bill, nor have I found a solution on Stack Exchange; many I have come across only supports version 1 of Magento.

So... are there any extensions available that will allow me to add in times as well as dates to indicate when a promotion should be available, and if not then how do I go about adding it in? This is my first Magento site I'm developing by the way, so don't be too surprised if I ask for further clarity on an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that presently there is any such Magento extension that will allow you to set from and to time on any cart rule for promotion. But yes it can be done by rewriting core files. 
Thus this requires some customization work.

You can contact any e-commerce development company for this customization work.

Hope you will find this answer useful

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had a feeling that there's no extension available, so I appreciate you confirming this assumption. I may contact a developer for this, but in the meantime I've decided to start doing it myself. I've already added the required fields by creating `app/code/[Vendor]/[Extension]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml`, so I'll go from there.